# Various versions of chrome on linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm looking for the way to conduct cross-browser compatibility test on my ubuntu. Firefox and opera don't cause problems, but I didn't find any guide how to install older versions of chrome. Do you know how to check my code in this browser on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take screenshots in different versions in [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots). Also you can browse there using different browsers, but you will need to pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no need to test compatibility against anything but the latest version of Chrome, since Chrome updates itself automatically. Just expect that anyone using Chrome to view your site will have the latest version.